# Redirect to URI with Apache2 as Reverse Proxy

Tags: remote-desktop, apache-http-server, proxy

I'm running a Reverse Proxy using Apache2, and I have the following vHost configured :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName rds.example.com
        Redirect / https://rds.example.com/RDWeb/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        # Proxy
        ServerName rds.example.com
        ProxyPreserveHost on
        SSLProxyEngine on
        SSLProxyVerify off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
        ProxyPass / https://backend01.example.com/
        ProxyPassReverse / https://backend01.example.com/
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/rds.example.com//fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/rds.example.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

When a client connects to http://rds.example.com or https://rds.example.com, I want to redirect him to https.//rds.example.com/RDWeb (the default Remote Desktop Web Services of Microsoft).

Actually, when a client connects, he is only redirected to https://rds.example.com with the beautiful IIS page.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mod_rewrite` to redirect to where you want - integrate this in the SSL vhost:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule .* /RDWeb/ [R,L]
```

Don't forget to enable mod_rewrite (use `a2enmod` if at all possible).

Comment: It worked like a charm, thank you so much ! But should I keep the `Redirect / https://rds.example.com/RDWeb/` directive in the SSL vHost ?

Comment: I don't see a redirect in your SSL vhost. Do you mean the non-SSL?

Comment: Oh yes sorry! It was in the non-SSL vHost. Should I keep it ?

Comment: Well, as far as I understand your requirements, you want any non-SSL requests being redirected into the SSL vhost - so you need a functions for this. Either you stay with your `Redirect` statement or employ something similar as in the SSL vhost using `mod_rewrite`. 
And by the way: maybe you even want a little bit more functionality for the non-SSL accessing parties (like HSTS headers, 301 based redirection...).